# Attaching license key to downloadable products in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9.3.6

I'm trying to find a way to attach a license key to either downloadable or virtual products.
Can't seem to find any extension that will help me achieve this.

What we're selling is an Anti-virus software, and it's crucial that we can attach these keys, when our customers buy the product.

Until now, we've been sending it out physically and just adding the license key on a piece of paper. But we want to digitalize it now.

Hope someone can be of assistence.

Answer (score 1):

Magento, by default provides the option add multiple private files which will be available to download once the order is invoiced.

To do so, go to **`Downloadable Information`** tab in the product in which you want to add the license.

Now click on **`Add New Row`** button under Links section to add new rows of links.

[image: add multiple downloadable links]

Click on **[...]** button under File sub-section to add files.

Now, click on **`Upload Files`** button to upload files.

Save the product by clicking on save button.

**Note:** The files added under **`Sample`** sub-section are publically available for download before purchase.

**Note:** The files added under **`File`** sub-section are added as private links which are available for download after purchase is complete.

**Update:** As per the updated requirement posted in comment, I would suggest checking below extension:

http://www.modifymage.com/magento-extensions/serial-codes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
So if I have, say 100 license keys for this software, i can add them as a what, csv file? 
So this file would contain all the keys, and when a customers buys the product, they will be send of these keys?

Comment: @MathiasDuedal, please check my update in the answer. I have added a link to paid module, which may help in your case. Sorry, I didn't think about this scenario while posting my answer initially.